# cardinality of final coalgebras in Top

Tags: euler-characteristics, coalgebras, gn.general-topology

Let P be a polynomial functor from Top to Top, by which I mean a functor of the form P(X) = ∐<sub>i ≥ 0</sub> S<sub>i</sub> × X<sup>i</sup> where the S<sub>i</sub> are finite sets, all but finitely many of which are empty.  Corresponding to P there is an ordinary polynomial p(x) = Σ<sub>i ≥ 0</sub> |S<sub>i</sub>| x<sup>i</sup>.  I believe that there is a final P-coalgebra X<sub>P</sub> in Top; the structure map X<sub>P</sub> -> P(X<sub>P</sub>) is a homeomorphism; the underlying set of X<sub>P</sub> is the final P-coalgebra in Set; and a basis for the open sets of X<sub>P</sub> is given by the preimages of the points of the targets of the maps X<sub>P</sub> -> P<sup>(n)</sup>(X<sub>P</sub>) -> P<sup>(n)</sup>(•) as n ranges over all nonnegative integers.

Examples are the Cantor space, corresponding to p(x) = 2x, and the space of binary trees, corresponding to p(x) = x^2 + 1.

My question is: if P and Q are two polynomial functors, such that neither p(x) nor q(x) is of the form x + k, and the spaces X<sub>P</sub> and X<sub>Q</sub> are homeomorphic, does it follow that the polynomials p(x) - x and q(x) - x have a common root?

More generally, consider all the spaces that can be formed starting with the collection of spaces X<sub>P</sub> (p(x) not of the form x + k) by taking disjoint unions and products.  Can I assign an algebraic number to each of these spaces in a way which is a homeomorphism invariant and commutes with sums and products?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but one could begin to investigate your first question by considering polynomials of the form *ax + k*, where *a* is a natural number greater than 1.  Maybe you already know that the answer to the question is "yes" in that case?  (If so, I'd be interested to see your answer.)

A point related to this, and to the general idea about algebraic numbers, is discussed here:

http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/04/reportback_on_bmc.html#c009149

There are also close relations with the theory described in [arXiv:math.DS/0411343](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DS/0411343) (an improved version of which appears in *Real and Complex Singularities*, ed. Paunescu et al, World Scientific 2007).  But there are differences too, e.g. you allow products but I didn't.